# html templates in asp net mvc views

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering what would be a better approach than creating every single view with a hard coded html.

The system I am creating today has a few dozen of views and I have manually created tables on it. I was thinking of creating a javascript function to build those tables passing an object as parameter containing html properties as ID, name, class and so on.

Is this a good approach or should I stick with the hard coded mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think very generic approach will lead to difficult solution and in any case you will need some markup somewhere. If you wand to use javascript and generate views on the client take a look into Single Page Applications and frameworks for them such as Backbone, Knockout, AngularJS. HTH